# How fetch like query with hibernate criteria?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using below mention code to find top 5 highest count tag name which starts with queryString from the table.

```
           Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Tag.class, "t");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("t.name", queryString, MatchMode.START));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("t.count"));
    criteria.setMaxResults(5);
    return findByCriteria(criteria);
```

By this code not getting the desired result. please make me correct if I am doing any mistake.

**QueryString** value is **ban**

Table **tag**

```
Id        Name             Count
101       ban               55
102       bangalore         66
103       tea               70
104       bangalore_traffic 78
105       roads             90
106       mc_D              45
```

so **result** should be like

```
Id        Name             Count
104      bangalore_traffic  78
102      bangalore          66
101      ban                55
```

Comment: So, what are the rows, what is the value of queryString, what is the result you expect, and what is the result you get?

Comment: I am getting blank **list** and passing "ban" in queryString. I have one record where tag name starts with ban.

Comment: You answered only one of my 4 questions. Not enough.

Comment: I edited plz read it again

Comment: You didn't change anything, and you're still not answering my questions. We can't help if you don't include the necessary information. Voting to close.

Comment: I added a sample data in my question please review again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112563/discussion-between-meeti-sharma-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: Sorry now a complete question is there.

Comment: The query string is probably not "ban". Maybe there is a hidden white-space at the beginning or the end of the string. Print its length. Print each of its characters. Use you debugger. Another possibility is that findByCriteria doesn't do what I imagine it does. Or that you're not targetting the correct database. Or that you forgot to commit all the rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use like following

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("name", queryString, MatchMode.START));
    criteria.addOrder(Property.forName("custId").desc("count"));
```

Where name anf custId is your persistence class variable name